# Find password application uses to access PDF-file in OS X

Tags: macos, pdf, encryption

I have a encrypted PDF-file that I don't know the (user) password to. However, I have an application that can opens and decrypts the file (temporarily) so that it is viewable in that application. Is there any way to trace the file request to see what password the application use to access the file?

Comment: Since you're probably interested in having an unencrypted file with the same plain text content rather than figuring out the password, I suggest you just print the PDF to a PDF file.

Comment: @UTF-8 Printing the PDF unfortunately isn't supported by the application.

Comment: Try another software to remove password not just to open it for reading. You can try https://smallpdf.com/unlock-pdf

Comment: @Rohitkr I'm unable to open the file for viewing in any other application because viewing the PDF requires knowing the password.